# validate method of embedded struct is not called using ozzo validation

Tags: go, struct-validation

I am using `"github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v4"`.
These are my structs:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    UUID          string `json:"uuid"`
    FirstUUID     string `json:"first_uuid"`
    SecondUUID    string `json:"second_uuid"`
    ThirdUUID     string `json:"third_uuid"`
    PhoneNumber   string `json:"phone_number"`
    Email         string `json:"email"`
    SkypeID       string `json:"skype_id"`
}

type MyOtherStruct struct {
    MyStruct
    City          string `json:"city"`
    Comment       string `json:"comment"`
    PersonnelID   string `json:"personnel_id"`
    FirstDate     string `json:"first_date"`
    SecondDate    string `json:"second_date"`
    FirstBoolean  bool   `json:"first_boolean"`
    SecondBoolean bool   `json:"second_boolean"`
}
```

These are validate methods:

```
func (m MyStruct) Validate() error {
    fmt.Println("calling MyStruct validator")

    err := validation.ValidateStruct(
        validation.Field(&uui.UUID, is.UUID),
        validation.Field(&uui.FirstUUID, validation.Required, is.UUID),
        validation.Field(&uui.SecondUUID, validation.Required, is.UUID),
        validation.Field(&uui.ThirdUUID, validation.Required, is.UUID),
        validation.Field(&uui.Email, validation.Required, is.Email),
        validation.Field(&uui.PhoneNumber, validation.Required, validation.Match(mobileRegexp)),
        validation.Field(&uui.SkypeID, validation.Required),
    )

    return err
}

func (m MyOtherStruct) Validate() error {
    fmt.Println("calling MyOtherStruct validator")

    err := validation.ValidateStruct(
        validation.Field(&uui.PersonnelID, validation.Match(personnelIDRegexp)),
        validation.Field(&uui.City, validation.Required),
        validation.Field(&uui.Comment),
        validation.Field(&uui.FirstDate, validation.Date(time.DateOnly)),
        validation.Field(&uui.SecondDate, validation.Date(time.DateOnly)),
    )

    return err
}
```

This is the request I send:

```
{
    "uuid": "1e57ef49-352f-4545-a43a-b51cad6c5a0a",
    "phone_number": "09124567891",
    "email": "email.address@gmail.com",
    "skype_id": "some_skype_id",
    "city": "a city",
    "personnel_id": "",
    "comment": "no comment for now!",
    "first_date": "",
    "second_date": "",
    "first_uuid": "94038913-2bdb-4dde-99fb-640a24e1c003",
    "second_uuid": "7fa0e242-841b-4de0-a3ce-e2b54ecd1bca",
    "third_uuid": "35ab6711-852e-42c8-aab3-dfb901a845f5",
    "first_boolean": true,
    "second_boolean": false
}
```

I expect `func (m MyStruct) Validate()` to be called regarding [this issue](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/issues/24), but I don't get the log `calling MyOtherStruct validator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code in the question has the same issue as [ozzo validation v4 returns field #0 cannot be found in the struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76811694/ozzo-validation-v4-returns-field-0-cannot-be-found-in-the-struct). Besides that, you should add the following code to `(MyOtherStruct).Validate`:

```golang
validation.Field(&m.MyStruct),
```

Try this demo (https://go.dev/play/p/CgyJq4WZemi):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    validation "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v4"
    "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/v4/is"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    UUID  string `json:"uuid"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

func (m MyStruct) Validate() error {
    fmt.Println("calling MyStruct validator")

    err := validation.ValidateStruct(
        &m,
        validation.Field(&m.UUID, is.UUID),
        validation.Field(&m.Email, validation.Required, is.Email),
    )

    return err
}

type MyOtherStruct struct {
    MyStruct
    City string `json:"city"`
}

func (m MyOtherStruct) Validate() error {
    fmt.Println("calling MyOtherStruct validator")

    err := validation.ValidateStruct(
        &m,
        validation.Field(&m.City, validation.Required),
        // The following line is necessary to make (MyStruct).Validate being called.
        validation.Field(&m.MyStruct),
    )

    return err
}

func main() {
    data := MyOtherStruct{}
    fmt.Printf("validation error: %v\n", data.Validate())
}
```

Please note that if you call `(MyStruct).Validate`, `(MyOtherStruct).Validate` won't be called because the former knows nothing about `MyOtherStruct`.